# SQL Server Grouping issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

1. `Customer ID, NAME, MonthlyIncome`
2. `Orders ID, CustomerKey, TotalCost`

I want join those two table into one, in the way that having total amount the bought in the shop.

```
CustomerKey, MonthlyIncome, TotalCost.
```

I have tried to group by `CustomerKey`, but I am not able to include the rest of the columns. Which query should I be using?

```
SELECT 
    fs.CustomerKey, SUM(fs.TotalCost) as TotalBought
FROM 
    FactOnlineSales fs
INNER JOIN 
    DimCustomer c on c.CustomerKey = fs.CustomerKey
GROUP BY 
    fs.CustomerKey
```

Comment: Just include and group by the extra columns...

Comment: Thanks. But including those extra columns would not break a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to group by CustomerKey, but not able to manage how to include rest of the columns.

[Just do it](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zOUTYrhxHtk/TtTfSqA3iqI/AAAAAAAABuY/hHyxLchsmpE/s1600/nike-just-do-it1.jpg):

```
SELECT fs.CustomerKey,
       c.MonthlyIncome,
       SUM(fs.TotalCost) as TotalBought
  FROM FactOnlineSales fs
       INNER JOIN DimCustomer c
         ON c.CustomerKey = fs.CustomerKey
 GROUP BY fs.CustomerKey,
          c.MonthlyIncome
```

Presumably `CustomerKey` is unique, so grouping by a less unique column isn't going to change the `SUM` total.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using - but if you're on SQL Server **2005** or newer, you could use the `OVER()` clause:

```
SELECT 
    fs.CustomerKey, 
    c.MonthlyIncome,
    TotalBought = SUM(fs.TotalCost) OVER(PARTITION BY fs.CustomerKey)
FROM 
    FactOnlineSales fs
INNER JOIN 
    DimCustomer c on c.CustomerKey = fs.CustomerKey
```

That basically gives you the `CustomerKey`, the `MonthlyIncome` and then sums the `TotalCost` for each `CustomerKey` and displays the appropriate value in your output. No need to do a `GROUP BY` in this case

Answer (score 1):

You may have an error in the ON clause of the join.
You used `CustomerKey` instead of `Customer ID` from the `DimCustomer` table.
For gouping: you must group by every column you don't aggregate on, so you can include `NAME` (so you can have descriptive customer) and  `MonthlyIncome`.

```
SELECT 
    c."Customer ID",
    c.NAME, 
    c.MonthlyIncome,
    SUM(fs.TotalCost) as TotalBought
FROM 
    FactOnlineSales fs INNER JOIN DimCustomer c 
    on c."Customer ID" = fs.CustomerKey
GROUP BY 
    c."Customer ID",
    c.NAME,
    c.MonthlyIncome
```